# How to pop thirdviewcontroller to firstviewcontroller in singleview app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my `app` I have three `uiviewcontroller`: firstviewcontroller, secondviewcontroller and thirdviewcontroller.

I go from firstviewcontroller to secondviewcontroller using navigationcontroller and then from secondviewcontroller to thirdviewcontroller

I want go back from thirdviewcontroller to fristviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)GoFirstView:(id)sender
{
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[Firstviewcontroller class]])
        {
            //Do not forget to import Firstviewcontroller.h

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP didn't specify that the UIViewControllers were subclasses

Comment: But I guess this is true in 95% of all cases.

Answer (score 8):

use below code:

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

also for moving to any particular viewController which is in navigation hierarchy you can use below code:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Comment: in your code go to rootviewcotroller not firstviewcontroller ?? but thanks for reply.

Comment: I think firstView Controller is only the rootview according to your viewController hierarchy ..